# i cant install virtualbox

Tags: 20.04, kernel, virtualbox, games, genymotion

the problem is when i tried isntall virtualbox

```
See "systemctl status virtualbox.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
● virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/virtualbox; generated)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-11-05 19:34:51 -05; 6ms ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 7239 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/virtualbox start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

nov 05 19:34:51 eli-desktop systemd[1]: Starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
nov 05 19:34:51 eli-desktop virtualbox[7239]:  * Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...
nov 05 19:34:51 eli-desktop virtualbox[7239]:  * No suitable module for running kernel found
nov 05 19:34:51 eli-desktop virtualbox[7239]:    ...fail!
nov 05 19:34:51 eli-desktop systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
nov 05 19:34:51 eli-desktop systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
nov 05 19:34:51 eli-desktop systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
```

Comment: How did you install virtual box, and which version of vbox?

Comment: i put in terminal  sudo apt-get install virtualbox

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms
```

This solved a similar issue for me in the past.

Kind regards,

Nicolas

Comment: nvoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
● virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/virtualbox; generated)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2021-11-06 10:13:23 -05; 5ms ago

Comment: Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 17646 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/virtualbox start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

nov 06 10:13:23 eli-desktop systemd[1]: Starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
nov 06 10:13:23 eli-desktop virtualbox[17646]:  * Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...
nov 06 10:13:23 eli-desktop virtualbox[17646]:  * No suitable module for running kernel found
nov 06 10:13:23 eli-desktop virtualbox[17646]:    ...fail!
nov 06 10:13:23 eli-desktop systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Comment: nov 06 10:13:23 eli-desktop systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
nov 06 10:13:23 eli-desktop systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.

Comment: it does not work